# What is the minimum openssl configuration needed for ssl / tls support?

Tags: configuration, openssl

I couldn't find any reference as to what is the minimum needed for SSL/TLS in openssl in order to reduce code size.  I see MatrixSSL only has aes, rc4, des3, idea, and rc2.  I see OpenSSL has all kinds of NO-xxx configurations available.  What would be the minimum requirement to reduce the bloat (~1M) created by openssl?  I only need it for sending an email from an application and linking in openssl as almost double the app .exe size. Thanks.

Comment: You should probably determine what features you want/need, state where you are with respect to your requirements, and then ask how to get into that configuration. To try and answer some of your question, part of the minimum config is probably TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.2; while using AES-128/CBC for TLS 1.0 and AES-GCM for TLS 1.2. You will still need to figure out key exchange/transport and authentication mechanisms you want to use.

Comment: That's the problem, I would like to remove item known not to be needed, do I need ec? pks? engines? etc...   What is definitely not needed for normal ssl/tls emails ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Cryptography Stack Exchange](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.